# Changing more than one Ascii number to characters

Tags: java, encryption, ascii

I have been trying to make a simple encryption program that changes a string into ascii numbers, minusing one to the value of each number, and then printing out the string by converting the ascii numbers back to letters.
I am wondering what code can be used do be able to achieve this.

```
for(int i= 0; i < textToEncrypt.length (); ++i) {
            char c = textToEncrypt.charAt(i);
            int j = (int)c - 1;
            System.out.println(j);

        }
```

so far i have been able to do the first part but not the second.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code instead of a question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use integer, just simply decrement your character.

You can write this:

```
    for(int i= 0; i < textToEncrypt.length (); ++i) {
        char c = textToEncrypt.charAt(i);
        c--;
        System.out.print(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to decript the text

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < textToEncrypt.length(); ++i) {
        char c = textToEncrypt.charAt(i);
        int j = (int) c - 1;
        System.out.println(j);
        arr[i] = j;
    }
    StringBuffer decriptText = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < textToEncrypt.length(); ++i) {
        decriptText.append(Character.toString((char) (arr[i] + 1)));
    }
    System.out.println(decriptText);
```

Comment: `++i` will work, but only because it is executed on the second iteration, `i++` should be preferred for readability. The intermediate array does not seem to be needed.